# How to skip the description step when uploading a file for a specific field?

Tags: media

in the media module's settings, there's a checkbox called "Skip available fields" that lets you skip filling out fields that are attached to your media when you add one.

In some cases, we need to let users enter a description for files that are uploaded and in other cases, no.

Does anybody know how to skip the available fields for a specific field of a specific content type ?  What kind of code or hook implementation is required, etc. ...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could probably acheive that by implementing

[`hook_field_attach_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_form/7)

and setting the required values (e.g `#required => TRUE` or unsetting the description element.).

The entity_type and entity values are available for conditionally showing / hiding data there.

Comment: Is there a way to name that hook so that it applies only to a specific content type ?  Because with the variables available, I can see that the description field is attached to my document file type but I don't see to which content type that document is attached ... so the hook applies to every description field, which is not what I want.

Comment: @agodin yes, the entity object is passed as a parameter so you can just check $entity->type

Comment: But $entity->type returns the value "document", which is the name of the filetype the description field is attached to ... I need to know the content type (blog post, article, etc.) of the field of type "document" that it's attached to.  Because for example, for content type "blog post", I'll want to use the description field and for content type "article", I want to skip it ...